# Is this proof of the four color theorem for infinite graphs legit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, nonstandard-analysis, infinite-graphs

So you got an infinite planar graph $G$. I will prove that it is four colorable.

So, construct an infinite number of statements about graphs:

- The first is "is four colorable"
- Next, for each vertex $v$ the statement "contains $v$"
- Next, for each edge $e$, the statement "contains $e$"

Every finite set of these statements is satisfiable. A finite set of those statements is satisfied by a finite subgraph of $G$ (which will be planar).

Therefore, we can use the [saturation principle](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/fun_with_nsmodels.pdf) to say there is a hypergraph $H$ that satisfies all of the above statements (a hypergraph is to a graph what a [hyperreal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) is to a real number). Color $H$ using four colors.

Now, for each vertex $v$ in $G$, we color it with the color used for $v$ in $H$. Now for every $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $G$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ will be adjacent and different colors in $H$. Therefore, the coloring is valid for $G$.

Here is the problem I have. We know by the [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle) that all $v_1$ and $v_2$ that are adjacent in $G$ are adjacent in $H$. The problem is, we need to use an infinite number of such statements. This would seem to imply that the proof would need to be infinitely long, sense it refers to an infinite number of individual statements.

For example, for an infinite hyperreal $H$, we know that $H > 1$, $H > 1 + 1$, $H > 1 + 1 + 1$, and so on, but we can't conclude that is bigger than every number, since that would be contradiction.

Can you use the transfer principle an infinite number of times but still have a finite proof?

Note: A hypergraph is a graph in a [nonstandard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the compactness theorem on the theory with axioms $c_n=\mathtt{red}\lor c_n=\mathtt{green} \lor c_n=\mathtt{blue}\lor c_n=\mathtt{yellow}$ for each node $n$ and $c_m\ne c_n$ for each edge $(m,n)$?

Comment: If this would work we could prove the four color theorem even without knowing what a graph is.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your analogy of "hypergraph" is to graph as hyperreal number is to real number holds water.  For one thing you seem to reify the edges $e$ and vertices $v$ of graph $G$ as if they had the same concrete existence as real numbers.  [Note that "contains $v$" seems to be more of a predicate than a statement (sentence), so issues about your universe of discourse are particularly relevant.]

Comment: @hardmath nonstandard analysis can be done with any mathematical object. See http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/fun_with_nsmodels.pdf.

Comment: @PyRulez:  If by "object" you mean a model of a first-order theory, esp. Varieties, then yes, we can create new models by taking ultraproducts.  I still see gaps in your proposed approach to the four-color theorem for infinite planar graphs.

Comment: @Py, can you formulate precisely the theorem you would like to prove and include it in the statement of your *question*?

Comment: The analogy between hypergraphs and hyperreals is wrong. Hypergraphs are, in a certain sense, multidimensional graphs, and are irrelevant to nonstandard analysis. Now, it's possible you mean "the thing that corresponds to hyperreals" when you use the term "hypergraphs" but if that's what you mean you have to formally define such an analog and call it something that's not *hypergraph* because that term is already taken for a different concept.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, as has already been pointed out above, Robinson's framework applies to any mathematical object, not merely the real numbers. For example [this recent article](http://www.logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/article/view/237/106) develops the foundations of differential geometry in Robinson's framework.

Comment: I believe my undergraduate thesis advisor showed me a proof of and had me work out the details of (iirc) exactly this in Internal Set Theory, but this was some years ago. The proof was done rigorously in the language of IST. I don't recall all the details, and I'm not sure if my advisor was the original source of the proof.

If it would be helpful, I can shoot my advisor an email and share the details if my memory was correct?

Comment: I found the result I had in my memory. It's Theorem 5.14 https://books.google.com/books?id=jgH3mmbs59IC&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Theorem. *Suppose* that any finite planar graph can be assigned a proper vertex $k$-coloring such that $k\le 4$. 
*Then* the same is true of any infinite planar graph.  See proof at:   https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Four_Color_Theorem_for_Finite_Maps_implies_Four_Color_Theorem_for_Infinite_Maps

Comment: Note that as Mirko observes, mentioning the hyperreals is unnecessary; this is really just a straightforward compactness argument.

Comment: Incidentally, here is a "combinatorial comment" on the way compactness is used here: [Konig's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma) - basically, compactness for countable languages - gives an immediate extension of FCT to *countable* graphs (consider the tree of legal colorings of initial segments of the set of vertices), but this doesn't extend to *uncountable* graphs.